# Цифры строк в листинге - как показать?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как активировать отображения номера строки в редакторе кода Delphi 7? Как во многих редакторах, для ориентирования в коде при его отладки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стандартном Delphi 7 нет такой возможности.
Номер строки есть только в строке состояния.

Основываясь на этом вопросе: "**[D7 show line numbers?](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_22484507.html)**" и ответах к нему, могу посоветовать только один сайт: **[CnPack Open Source Projects](http://www.cnpack.org/showlist.php?id=39&lang=en)**.

На нем китайские умельцы выложили спец. пакет для IDE со множеством улучшений, в том числе, с отображением номеров строк слева от рабочей области.

Comment: Хороший пакет, давно пользуюсь... Но если компьютер не современный, он тормозит разработку, листинги мерцают и прочее.